# PHP. cкрипт сбора статистики поисковых запросов

Tags: php, поисковые-системы, google-search

Как реализовать данную фишку?

В основном нужны запросы статистики с google.

Answer (score 1):

Я читал об этом... В общем, это было вполне реально, когда google работал через http. Запрос можно было получить через HTTP_REFERER. Сейчас же, когда он работает через https, реферер не передаётся. Так что, насколько я понимаю, способа нет. Но такая фишка вполне возможна с яндексом.

Да, способ для яндекса (ну и для старого гугла) описан [в этой статье](http://rche.ru/599_kak-uznat-zapros-po-kotoromu-prishli.html). Не буду сюда её всю копировать, надеюсь вам не сложно перейти по ссылке.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics, их API и параметр Traffic Sources/[ga:keyword](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=traffic_sources&jump=ga_keyword)?

> if a visitor used organic search to reach your property, the keywords used by visitors

GAPI [php interface](http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/)